# Use Office References and Treeview OCX from File

Tags: ms-access, dll, activex, ocx

we have an over the years grown Access Database which is making use of a Treeview Element and the Excel Office reference. With some Windows Updates we ran into problems with the Treeview (throws random errors about ActiveX control for each input: mouse move, mouse click, etc.). 
Some customers use Access 2003 (we 2007) and therefore some errors are thrown on the first time opening the database because the references have to be adjusted.

I want to solve those problems by taking the office 2003 reference (I think it should be the `MSO.dll`) and store it in the database as an OLE object. On Startup I want to 'extract' the file and use it as a reference for the office libraries, so that I am kind of independent from the installed Office version on the machine.
Furthermore I thought about doing the same thing with the `MSCOMCTL.OCX` so that it can not get corrupted from Windows Updates anymore. I hope to gain more stability in the application.

My questions would be: Is it possible at all to use the office references from a local file instead of the windows dir?

And is it possible to use an ActiveX control directly from a local file instead of the registered one through RegSvr32?

If so, any links or information how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Matthias

Comment: These DLLs are attractive attack surfaces since they are so common.  Microsoft hasn't been shy lately in patching them, making fundamental changes to them.  The scheme you are contemplating just makes it worse, mixing incompatible versions of them.  You are not the only one using them.  They have to be registered anyway, can't do that with a file in a dbase.  An app like this is doomed to end up running in a VM if you don't maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know if it's *possible*, but I certainly would do everything I could to avoid going down that road. The potential for *even worse* stability problems and general weirdness would be significant. I would push for either

- standardizing on an Office version (**not** 2003), or
- using a third-party treeview control from a reputable developer and using late binding to replace the Excel reference(s).

Comment: I maybe found a solution to the Excel references. I will just have a table with the reference names of the different Excel-Versions and if one is broken I look if the others do exist. There also seems to be a function References.AddFromFile, maybe I can use that to handle the reference problem. I will look for a third-party treeview, but how will that be provided. As an ocx file too? Maybe I can use the MS treeview OCX the same way, so that it is independent from microsoft updates?